# How to hide a common piece of text from a website

Tags: css, web, hidden

So for example on something like Redit, if I wanted to hide the "give award" text which shows on every post how would I be able to hide it from appearing multiple times?

What the text part I want to block looks like
[image: (What the text part I want to block looks like)]

Comment: Can you create [a minimal reprodcuicble example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. btw thanks..

Answer (score -1):

You would want to apply a stylesheet that hides the elements matching a given selector. I'm not sure how you are applying the stylesheet, but a selector with a display property could be used:

```
.class_selector_to_hide {
  display: none;
}
```